# Window dividers have slipped out

Tags: windows

I don't even know the appropriate words, so good luck understanding this! Our formal dining room has a large window with dividers that are between two glass pieces.  There is the half moon window above it, but two white divider pieces have slipped out and fallen midway down the larger window. Is there any way to remove these myself?

Comment: A photo might help, as would knowing the window construction.

Comment: Are You able to get cash back from window producer? That thing shouldn't have happen I guess. At least, I got no memory of anything like that. Are Your windows new? Any warranty?

Answer (score 1):

I pride myself on being able to fix many things, but the inside of window that's probably gas sealed isn't one of them (maybe someone else here can chime in with some window magic).

Replacing the window package I could do; *fix* your window, not so much.

If you can get the window out of the frame and take it somewhere, it'd be cheaper but you're most likely going to have to board up the window for quite some time while it's in the shop.

Ordering a new  one and having it on hand for a swap out would be ideal. I'd have an eye on the other windows too, though. How soon until they go; consider having a complete new install on the dining room package.